# Wysiwyg image upload button not there - Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, wysiwyg

The image upload button on the Wysiwyg is not there on my Magento 1 site.

[image]

Comment: you need to install flash player on your system

Comment: Thanks, but the suggested solution did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in a different browser or try in in the incognito window.

Comment: Thanks, but the suggested solution did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Allow Flash into the Browser then refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

### Option - 1

Try this extension: https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader

### Option - 2

Check media folder is present on following locations or not. If not then copy media folder from default Magento version.

1) skin/adminhtml/default/default

2) /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/system/storage

3) /js/tiny_mce/plugins/

4) design/adminhtml/default/default/template/

Comment: Thanks, but the suggested solution did not help.